# How to do a scroll animation in Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I'm new to Android programming. I'm working on an app that requires some form of animation. Please take a look at [image: this]

I want an animation where a scroll rolls down at the top with this text in it as soon as this activity starts & rolls up when the connect button is pressed. I have no clue where or how to begin with the animation. Any kind of links to tutorials or posts on StackOverflow will be of much help.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is *really* ***really*** broad, I'll give you a broad answer as well.

I think by "scrolling animation" you mean an animation in which a black (or some other color) area slowly covers up/reveals the screen. I don't know why would this look cool, but whatever.

#### Step 1

Create an animation XML file. In this file, you would specify that the view should translate downwards by x pixels where x is the height of the screen. And create another animation file. This time, specify that it should translate upwards.

If you need help creating XML view animations, have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html)

Now you have two animations - move upwards and downwards.

#### Step 2

Okay, now you should create a custom view. You can start by doing this:

```
public class ScrollingView extends View {

}
```

And implement all the required constructors.

Override `onDraw` like this:

- cover the whole view with black or some other color
- draw the scroll at the top of the view. The scroll should be an image like this one:

[image]

If you don't like using an image, you can draw it yourself, using code!

You can get help on this [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-custom-views--mobile-14548)

#### Step 3

In `onCreate` of your activity, create a `ScrollingView`. This view should be as wide as the screen and as high as the screen. Position the view at (0, 0) and bring it to front so that it covers up the whole screen.

#### Step 4

Next, apply the animation you created in step 1 to the scrolling view.